# Can 2sxc create an audit trail or assign versions to a new Content Type entry?

Tags: 2sxc

I'm recording Content Type items in a "log", and would like to save dated versions or "differences" when other users edit the item.

Is this possible with 2sxc? I've not come across any techniques for this on the site - but only have taken a couple days to learn this so far.

Reports come in to our fire station and we want others to be able to edit the reports - but also to see a history of the edits also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options

1. By default, all changes are automatically logged already in a history. So technically everything is already there. The thing that is missing is the UI to look at it and maybe even restore items, + the internal API to retrieve data. If you want to use this, you could just do some sql yourself or sponsor the missing pieces - ca. 2-3 days of work. http://2sxc.org/en/Contact
2. You could do something that copies each item instead of editing. There is a copy-function you can find in the details admin. This would work, but would not be fully reliable as the copies can still be modified, so it depends on how important this change-log is

With love from Switzerland...

Comment: For now I'm relieved to hear it is in history. I'll consider launching into this down the road. I've some time but minimal ability to sponsor right now. Thanks!